# How to get feedback on JUnit Testing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testing, junit, testcase

I have a simple JUnit test in Eclipse.

```
public class HelloTest extends TestCase {
    CalculatorEngine ce;

    public HelloTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ce = new CalculatorEngine();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.tearDown();
        ce = null;
    }

    public void test1() {
        assertTrue(ce.doCalculation("1+5").equals("2"));
    }
}
```

The test fails because 1+5 does not equal 2.  If I change 1+5 to 1+1 the test is successful.

How can I get some feedback/output from JUnit to determine what the result was when the test failed? In other words is there any way I can find out that ce.doCalculation("1+5") returned 6 instead of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [assertEquals](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20long%29) method for your check

```
assertEquals("Unexpected result!", 2, ce.doCalculation("1+5"));
```

(available to check/compare most types - have a look at the API documentation).

Comment: That's correct, thanks! I actually solved it myself and was in the process of posting the answer when your answer came up. It will let me mark it as correct in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write more descriptive tests using the [assertThat](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html) api e.g:-

```
assertThat(1, is(2))
```

or

```
assertThat(1, is(not(2))
```